# Convert PDF/A-1b to PDF/A-2

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, ocr, document

I have a PDF/A-1b file, but I need it to be PDF/A-2 or even PDF/A-3.

Is this somehow possible? Are there any tools?

I know it may be a generic question, but I am currently thinking about all possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this somehow possible?

Yes.

I have not done a thorough review of the differences between PDF/A-1B and PDF/A-[2|3]B, but as far as I am aware PDF/A-1B is **more** restrictive than the other two. So there is not much too. At a minimum, only two changes required.

1. Change Metadata XML content to claim PDF/A-[2|3]B conformance, instead of PDF/A-1B.
2. Change version header from `%PDF-1.3` to `%PDF-1.7`.

Though, I would recommend using a PDF/A validator to make sure that the changes are non-breaking.

> Are there any tools?

Yes, the company I work for has a free online tool.
https://www.pdftron.com/pdf-tools/pdfa-converter/